# Is it possible to replay from Aeron Cluster?

Tags: aeron

We would like to use Aeron as persistent queue.
Is it possible to setup Aeron Cluster to provide

- replication, and
- possibility to replay (like Aeron Archive)
  for the clients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Aeron Cluster requires that logic to process events from Cluster's replicated log has to be implemented as a ClusteredService.

Having Cluster run without services and providing a replay feature similar to how replay from the Archive works is a [feature that is being considered](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/issues/1177).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was not clear to me from the doc and api...

Comment: @michael-barker, hi. How long might it take to implement the feature you mentioned?

Comment: The feature is not currently sponsored, so it has no specific time line.